# Run JavaScript function on dynamic elements as they are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the following function to be applied to some dynamic elements on my page which are loaded through ajax. It works on clicking the elements but I want it to execute as soon as the elements are loaded. How to do it?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $( document ).on( 'click', '.wraption', function() {
      $('img.wraption').wraption();
    });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: How do you load these elements via Ajax?

Comment: Through another JavaScript function and load them in a div.

Comment: Just add this `$('img.wraption').wraption();` once the element is loaded.

Comment: Aha... Just call `wraption` after loading elements

Comment: Yo need to load it after the Ajax data is loaded .. so it will help us to help when you put youre ajax code snipped here

Comment: It works with calling the wraption after loading elements. Thanks guys :)